# Show sample images on the webapp to use for 'Upload Picture' and 'Submit'

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I want my web app to show a set of sample images (sample images I will give myself)- and the user can select from among those pictures to use for the 'upload' and 'submit' button on the screen.

Basically I am deploying my ML model that makes different predictions from the image the user uploads. I want to give a few sample images to use instead so the user can better understand the models perspective.

I am not a pro on the dev side and I am having a lot of difficulty finding something similar to it. My front end is HTML, CSS, JS and my backend is on Flask.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to display images is to have divs with background images and use flex for styling. A div will be more flexible when it comes to scaling your styles.

// css

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 5%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 
 .imageContainer {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imageContainer"></div>
  <div class="imageContainer"></div>
  <div class="imageContainer"></div>
  <div class="imageContainer"></div>
  <div class="imageContainer"></div>
<div>
```

You can then add more styles to your 'imageContainer' div as you add the upload buttons.

Comment: Thank you but this isnt what I was looking for. I am basically looking for something similar to how we upload images on Facebook for profile pictures from the existing pictures on our profile.